# Android NDK accessing native bluetooth functions bluedroid

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-ndk

I'm trying to see what sort of native bluetooth functions i can access using JNI and Android NDK.  I've tried two different approaches:  Using a prebuilt .so or building my own.  As far as using a prebuilt .so I've pulled libbluetooth_jni.so off a Samsung Galaxy S4 using adb pull.  However, I cannot find the source code for this (bluetooth_jni.c??) online and can't identify any accessible functions.

Secondly, I tried to download the source for bluedroid from
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/
However, I am having trouble building this.

Currently when I try to run ndk-build, I get the following errors:
    undefined reference to '__android_log_print'
    undefined reference to 'socket_local_client_connect'
    undefined reference to 'str_parms_destroy'

I added to this line:
    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
and it got rid of the  first error.  However, I'm not sure how to get rid of the others.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to compile or otherwise get an .so in order to access native bluetooth functions??

Comment: You will not be able to do much useful on a typical secured consumer device, as you cannot get permission to bypass the stack and talk directly to the bluetooth chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libbluedroid` is specific for some hardware; on Samsung S4 you will find different bluetooth libraries. If you need to go beyond the public bluetooth API, you will probably not find a common ground.

Another problem that you face is that these libraries cannot work in app context, as [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429063/chris-stratton) explained in his comment. They were designed to work with the media server with its special permissions.

Regarding the specific references, they are in `libcutils.so`. The recent discussion about this non-public library is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013206/shared-memory-in-android-ndk).